# Access document-term matrix without calling .fit_transform() each time

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, nlp, text-mining, countvectorizer

If I've already called `vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)`, is the only way to later print the document-term matrix to call `vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)` again?

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
corpus = ['the', 'quick','brown','fox']
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')
vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus) # Returns the document-term matrix
```

My understanding is by doing above, I've now saved terms into the `vectorizer` object. I assume this because I can now call `vectorizer.vocabulary_` without passing in `corpus` again.

So I wondered why there is not a method like `.document_term_matrix`?

Its seems weird that I have to pass in the `corpus` again if the data is now already stored in `vectorizer` object. But per the docs, only `.fit`, `.transform`, and `.fit_transform`return the mattrix.

**Docs:** http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.fit

**Other Info:**

I'm using Anaconda and Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply assign the fit to a variable `dtm`, and, since it is a [Scipy sparse matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html), use the [`toarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.toarray.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.toarray) method to print it:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
corpus = ['the', 'quick','brown','fox']
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')
dtm = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)

# vectorizer object is still fit:
vectorizer.vocabulary_
# {'brown': 0, 'fox': 1, 'quick': 2}

dtm.toarray()
# array([[0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 1],
#        [1, 0, 0],
#        [0, 1, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

although I guess for any realistic document-term matrix this will be *really* impractical... You could use the [`nonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.nonzero.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.nonzero) method instead:

```
dtm.nonzero()
# (array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int32), array([2, 0, 1], dtype=int32))
```